# How do I change the position of a button with the page height via jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a button that it scroll in page  and its style is:

```
button{
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0%;
}
```

Now I want to change that position so that : `bottom = $(document).height() - 10rem`.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css method (in pixels):

```
var heightVal = $(document).height() - 10;
$("button").css("height", heightVal + 'px');
```